# Add elements of custom array SwiftUI

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

So I have a struct of `Dice` that has a few properties attached to it. I want to be able to add them all together so I have one clean value. Here is the struct:

```
struct Dice: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var displayValue: String
    var initialValue: Int
    var endingValue: Int
            
    mutating func roll() {
        let randomInt = Int.random(in: initialValue..<endingValue)
        displayValue = "\(randomInt)"
        print("Initial: \(initialValue), EndingValue: \(endingValue), Display: \(displayValue)")
    }
}
```

They are stored within an array here: `@State var viewArray: [Dice] = []` and then displayed in an ForEach here:

```
ForEach(0..<viewArray.count, id: \.self) { index in
    DiceView(dice: viewArray[index])
    .onTapGesture {
        self.viewArray.remove(at: index)
        withAnimation(.spring()) {
          
        }
    }
}
```

The thing I'm trying to do is grab the `displayValue` of each item in the `viewArray` and add them together. What is the best way of doing so? I'm assuming I need to create some sort of array based on the property of `displayValue` and then add that array together, but I haven't come across it yet.

Comment: So you want to create one string out of all the displayValue strings in the array, I would suggest `map` to get the property into an array and then `joined` to make one string from the array

Comment: Whoops! That's my fault, the `displayValue` should actually be an `Int` but essentially yes. How would I use map to grab the displayValue property directly? The examples I see are for grabbing just the direct values, but since my array is a custom type how do I map the custom values?

Comment: Not sure I follow, the main usage of `map` is to get a single property. Maybe you should read up on using `map`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you can try `map` + `reduce`.

Assuming the `displayValue` is of type `Int` (as you mentioned in the comments):

```
var viewArray: [Dice] = ...
let sum = viewArray.map(\.displayValue).reduce(0, +)
```

---

Assuming the `displayValue` is of type `String` you need to convert it to `Int` first:

```
var viewArray: [Dice] = ...
let sum = viewArray.map(\.displayValue).compactMap(Int.init).reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I ended up solving it but a little be more verbose:
`let rollValues = viewArray.compactMap { Int($0.displayValue) }
        let total = rollValues.reduce(0,+)
        print("\(total)")`

Same principle but different method I think. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Per @joakim I ended up solving this by creating:

```
 let rollValues = viewArray.compactMap { Int($0.displayValue) }
    let total = rollValues.reduce(0,+)
    print("\(total)")
```

and then assigning that to the variable I needed to display. Worked like a charm!